# Element Follows Cursor Only When Hovering Over Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a circular ball following the cursor in my React project. However I want it only to appear when the cursor hovers over the button and nothing else.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/MWwzXOX)

```
let mouseX = 0
let mouseY = 0
let ballX = 0
let ballY = 0
let speed = 0.2

const Page = () => {

const ballRef = React.useRef(null)


  const animate = React.useCallback(() => {

    if (ballRef && ballRef.current) {
      let distX = mouseX - ballX
      let distY = mouseY - ballY
      ballX = ballX + distX * speed
      ballY = ballY + distY * speed
      ballRef.current.style.left = ballX + "px"
      ballRef.current.style.top = ballY + "px"
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }, [ballRef, mouseX, mouseY, ballX, ballY])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const onMouseMove = event => {
      mouseX = event.pageX
      mouseY = event.pageY
    }

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove)

    animate()

    return () => document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove)
  }, [])  

 return (
   <>
     <button>BUTTON</button>
     <div ref={ballRef} className="ball"></div>
     <div class="divs"></div>
     <div class="divs"></div>
   </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the beginning of your CSS will give the basic effect you are looking for:

```
#app button:hover + .ball {
  display: block;
}

.ball {
  display: none;
}
```

This first line here assumes that .ball will be added to the DOM immediately after the button.

If you want the ball to be clipped inside the button, you should rearrange the HTML in your React script so that the `.ball` div is inside the `<button>` element and then update the button's CSS (since the ball is then contained inside the button you actually won't need the CSS lines above, but if you keep them, just remove the "+" sign).

Updated part in the JS:

```js
return (
   <>
     <button>BUTTON
         <div ref={ballRef} className="ball"></div>
     </button>
     <div class="divs"></div>
     <div class="divs"></div>
   </>
  );
```

Updated part in the CSS:

```css
button{
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working however the ball itself is not clipped inside the button. Any idea, with CSS, on how to accomplish that? I'm thinking `overflow: hidden` but that didn't seem to work. https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/MWwzXOX

Comment: I updated the answer. For overflow: hidden; to work, the ball element needs to be inside the button element and the button's CSS position needs to be "relative".